# TypeScript Property 'navigation' is missing in type but required in type 'Props' React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

In a React Native App, I understand that when you pass your RootNavigator inside createAppContainer and export it, the navigation `prop` is implicitly made available in all child components.

```
export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

I have this component that is supposed to navigate to another screen using the navigation prop. I defined an interface for the props of this component like this:

**props interface for ComponentA:**

```
interface Props {
  count: number;
  navigation: NavigationStackProp<{quizId: number}>;
}
```

Now I render ComponentA like this:

```
...
render() {
    return (
        <ComponentA count={0} /> // TypeScript screams here that I am not passing the navigation props
    );
}
```

If I pass the navigation prop with ComponentA like this:

```
<ComponentA count={0} navigation={props.navigation} />
```

TypeScript is satisfied.

My question therefore is, do I have to pass navigation prop explicitly like this? It doesn't feel right to me. Is there a way I can suppress TypeScript warnings for this particular situation.

I am new to TypeScript so this might be something trivial but I will appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use optional props by having `?`

```
interface Props {
  count: number;
  navigation?: NavigationStackProp<{quizId: number}>;
}
```